# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning randomly occurs

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, I'm new to discord.js and I am trying to write a discord bot. I am using snekfetch to retrieve data from this URL: https://crystalmathlabs.com/tracker/api.php?type=comprankings&competition=19326

It works, but I sometimes get these errors:

```
//first error from first command run        
(node:17512) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 500 Internal Server Error
        at _response.transport.request.then (C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\discord-bot\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:193:21)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    (node:17512) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)

//second error from the first command run a second time
    (node:17512) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
        (node:17512) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 500 Internal Server Error
            at _response.transport.request.then (C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\discord-bot\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:193:21)
            at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
        (node:17512) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)

//command run a third time, and it works            
alt_life,3286389,5520479,2234090
            dookie_milk,5570464,7617703,2047239
            man_of_hyrup,123827,2152761,2028934
            iron_to_live,551433,2095151,1543718
```

Does anyone have any idea why they sometimes occur?

NOTE: I didn't include the full output after the code works, just the first few lines

EDIT:

After catching the error and printing it, I receive this:

```
{ Error: 500 Internal Server Error
    at _response.transport.request.then (C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\discord-bot\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:193:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  request: undefined,
  body: <Buffer ef bb bf 2d 34>,
  raw: <Buffer ef bb bf 2d 34>,
  ok: false,
  headers:
   [Object: null prototype] {
     ':status': 500,
     date: 'Mon, 03 Jun 2019 10:16:42 GMT',
     'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
     'set-cookie':
      [ '__cfduid=d6f57812d6ec549bbc54fd0f8ce59da441559557002; expires=Tue, 02-Jun-20 10:16:42 GMT; path=/; domain=.crystalmathlabs.com; HttpOnly',
        'flood=22fcd3b2889875eb86281892903980a9; expires=Thu, 04-Jul-2019 10:16:42 GMT; Max-Age=2678400; domain=crystalmathlabs.com' ],
     'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains',
     'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
     'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
     'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
     'expect-ct':
      'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"',
     server: 'cloudflare',
     'cf-ray': '4e10e9c48f7b3621-MAN' },
  statusCode: 500,
  statusText: 'Internal Server Error' }
```

Comment: The errors aren't really the promise rejection errors. They are server errors that you aren't catching. You should catch them and work out why your request is causing a 500 error – though it may be nothing to do with you but entirely the fault of the remote server. You just need to handle it.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up that its not a fault on my part. I have added the outcome after catching and printing the error. How should I go about handling this? just attempt the code again?

Comment: If you caught the promise rejection and you see still the warning, then probably there's some other promise not handled or maybe your `catch` code is throwing another error

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that was a printout of the error. I'm just unsure how to handle this, should I just repeat the original code until it runs successfully?

Comment: nvm thank you, to solve it I just put it in a while loop and broke out of it once the code was successful

Comment: the way you handle errors depends only on your application. Once you know how to catch exceptions, the code you run inside the catch is up to you. However, if I understand correctly, just using a while loop with no more control could result in an infinite loop if your exception keeps occuring, you may want to use some counter to avoid too many retries.

Comment: i spoke to the devs of CML and they mentioned the issue was on their side, so i decided to keep it in a loop. i plan to keep watch on it to see whats the max amount of tries it'll do before being successful (about 1500 seems to be peak) and i'm going to build in an auto failure after that many iterations. Apparently, they reject requests when theres too many at once and thats the issue, their servers are just overloaded.